# Why do objects appear more obvious in a dark room when we indirectly look at them?

Tags: visible-light, vision

I am currently in my room and it's dark (of course not an absolute darkness as you know yourself).

When I look directly at the ceiling lamp which has been turned-off for half an hour, I **can't** see it. But when I indirectly look at it (for example, looking $0.5$ m further than the lamp on the ceiling) I can see the lamp.

Even the objects that I can directly see are more obvious when I indirectly look at them.

Even my sister also said she has experienced the same thing.

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: This is a biology question; the answer is related to the distribution of light sensors in your eye.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averted_vision